# Shopify cart attributes aren't showing up on the admin side

Tags: attributes, shopify, cart

On my cart page I have three attribute fields. I'd like the customers responses to the questions to be passed through to the Additional Information part of the order in the Shopify admin.

The issue is that they are visible on the customers side but the information is not making it to the order.

I'm able to get them to work properly on a fresh development store but not on the actual store. This tells me there is some conflict with one of the apps or the theme. After some digging, I also found that I could look at /cart.js to see if the attributes are appearing there and they are not. Unfortunately, I've reached the end of my ability to troubleshoot and need some help figuring out where I might be going wrong.

Here's the link to my store: https://test-tory-2.myshopify.com/ the password is **chayrt**

**Some additional information:**

The code is located just before the closing `</form>` tag on the cart

Here's the form code itself.

```
  <p class="cart-attribute__field">
    <label for="billing-email">Billing email</label>
    <input id="billing-email" type="text" name="attributes[Billing email]" value="{{ cart.attributes["Billing email"] }}">
  </p>
```

Comment: What is your cart attribute code?
Should look like this ...
<p class="cart-attribute__field">
  <label for="your-name">Your name</label>
  <input id="your-name" type="text" name="attributes[Attribute name]" value="{{ cart.attributes["Your name"] }}">
</p>

Comment: The important part of the code above is name="attributes[Attribute name]" another possible problem is that your code isn't associated with your form and so isn't being posted. Needs to be either in the {% form %} tag or associated with the form with an attribute form="{{ product_form_id }}". I had a look at your store and couldn't see where the attribute fields are. Try adding form="{{ product_form_id }}" to the cart attribute code first.

Comment: @pete Thanks for your notes. I added some additional information about where the code is located as well as the code itself to the post. I realized I had customer accounts turned on, so I switched those off that way you can get to the cart page. 

In a blank dev store the form works, I see the attributes in /cart.js, and they appear on the order in the admin. However on this store, they aren't being passed to /cart.js for some reason. I'm guessing it's a theme or app conflict but I'm not sure how to go about troubleshooting from here.

Comment: Can you just try adding ```form="cart"``` to the input and testing again?